# Grouping Array result set based on same key values

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following array after querying into the database

```
$soundcloud_uploads=array(
array('release_id'=>33,'song_id'=>1,'artist_name'=>'omer aslam'),
array('release_id'=>33,'song_id'=>2,'artist_name'=>'omer aslam'),
array('release_id'=>34,'song_id'=>1,'artist_name'=>'Robbie')
);
```

what i am trying to do is to convert the array into something like following based on the same value for `release_id`.

```
$soundcloud_uploads=array(
    array(
      array('release_id'=>33,'song_id'=>1,'artist_name'=>'omer aslam'),
      array('release_id'=>33,'song_id'=>2,'artist_name'=>'omer aslam'),
    ),
    array('release_id'=>34,'song_id'=>1,'artist_name'=>'Robbie')
    );
```

currently i have the following code using the `foreach` loop which somehow achieves the same thing that i want

```
$soundcloud_uploads = array(
    array('release_id' => 33, 'song_id' => 1, 'artist_name' => 'omer aslam'),
    array('release_id' => 33, 'song_id' => 2, 'artist_name' => 'omer aslam'),
    array('release_id' => 34, 'song_id' => 1, 'artist_name' => 'Robbie')
);
$convert = array();
foreach ($soundcloud_uploads as $row) {
    $convert[$row['release_id']][] = $row;
}
```

which gives the following output

```
Array
(
    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [release_id] => 33
                    [song_id] => 1
                    [artist_name] => omer aslam
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [release_id] => 33
                    [song_id] => 2
                    [artist_name] => omer aslam
                )

        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [release_id] => 34
                    [song_id] => 1
                    [artist_name] => Robbie
                )

        )

)
```

but how can i make it more efficient and optimized as the result rest is going to be big and using this approach if i have `1000` records, i will have to iterate `2000` times once for arranging them into the desired format and then sending /uploading them in form of playlists to soundcloud.

**EDIT : Describing the DB schema and the whole scenario why i could not accomplish it via mysql query**

i am working on a site where users can upload and distribute their music to stores in form of releases / albums. Those uploaded and approved releases could then be sent / uploaded to soundcloud from a form where they could select to upload either all tracks inside a specific release as a playlist or each song as a separate track.

**When are the selected songs uploaded**

1. They can choose current date to upload it right away by when they hit save.

OR

2. They can choose a date in future to schedule the upload.

The selected tracks details are saved inside a table named 
`soundcloud_upload` which saves every selected track detail against their `release_id`, which means if i have 5 tracks inside a release and select to upload all of them, on hitting save every track detail would be saved as a separate record, schema for the table is added below.

The first part is simple and straight and implemented, the second scheduling part is where i am now and involves a cron job which will run every day and selected all those records from the `soundcloud_upload` table joining with other tables for the detail where `upload_date` matches the `current date` and the `upload_type` is `scheduled`. 
The query and tables schemas i am using is as follows

```
SELECT `sc`.*, `rp`.*, `l`.`Name` AS `LabelName`, 
        `l`.`ContactName`, `l`.`ContactEmail`, `l`.`soundcloudUsername`, 
        `l`.`soundcloudPassword`, `l`.`youtubeUsername`, `l`.`youtubePassword`, 
        `mg`.`Name` AS `MainGenre`, `g`.`Genre`, `u`.`Username` FROM 
        `soundcloud_upload` AS `sc`
             LEFT JOIN `ReleaseProd` AS `rp` ON sc.ReleaseId=rp.ReleaseId AND rp.Processed IS NOT NULL
             LEFT JOIN `Label` AS `l` ON l.LabelId=rp.LabelId
             LEFT JOIN `MainGenre` AS `mg` ON mg.MainGenreId=rp.MainGenreId
             LEFT JOIN `Genre` AS `g` ON g.GenreId=rp.GenreId
             LEFT JOIN `Users` AS `u` ON u.UserId=rp.UserId WHERE (sc.uploadDate='2016-12-10') AND 
    (l.soundcloudUsername IS NOT NULL) AND (l.soundcloudPassword IS NOT NULL) 
AND (sc.upload_type='scheduled') AND 
        (sc.IsUploaded=0 OR sc.IsUploaded=2)
```

The schema for the tables necessary to determine if i can achieve the desired format of the result set are as below.

soundcloud_upload

```
+----------------+-----------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type                        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-----------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ReleaseId      | int(11)                     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SongId         | int(11)                     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| isClip         | tinyint(1)                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| trackName      | varchar(100)                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| trackBio       | varchar(3000)               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| category       | varchar(20)                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tags           | varchar(3000)               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IsPlaylist     | tinyint(1)                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| isPublic       | tinyint(1)                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| isDownloadable | tinyint(1)                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| PlaylistID     | int(11)                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TrackID        | int(11)                     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| purchaseUrl    | varchar(500)                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| uploadDate     | date                        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| createDate     | date                        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| IsUploaded     | tinyint(1)                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| clipStart      | varchar(10)                 | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| clipEnd        | varchar(10)                 | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| error_logs     | text                        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| upload_type    | enum('instant','scheduled') | NO   |     | instant |       |
+----------------+-----------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Releases

```
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type                          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| ReleaseId                  | int(11)                       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| Name                       | varchar(100)                  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| UserId                     | int(11) unsigned              | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| rerelease                  | tinyint(1)                    | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| ReleaseNotes               | mediumtext                    | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| releaseDescription         | varchar(3000)                 | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| Catalog                    | varchar(20)                   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| CoverFile                  | varchar(200)                  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| AddDate                    | timestamp                     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| ReleaseDate                | date                          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| Howlong                    | int(11)                       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| EffectiveDate              | date                          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| iTunesPreOrderDate         | date                          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| SoundcloudDate             | date                          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| VariousArtists             | char(1)                       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| ArtistId                   | int(11)                       | NO   | MUL | -1                |                |

| Composer                   | varchar(255)                  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| MainGenreId                | int(11)                       | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| GenreId                    | int(11)                       | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| Language                   | varchar(3)                    | NO   |     | en                |                |
| SubgenreId                 | int(11)                       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| UPCCode                    | varchar(13)                   | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                |
| ReleaseType                | int(11)                       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| TracksQty                  | tinyint(4)                    | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| PhysicalRelease            | char(1)                       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| LabelId                    | int(11)                       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
```

Labels

```
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                     | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| LabelId                   | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| Name                      | varchar(50)      | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                             |
| ContactName               | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| ContactEmail              | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| secondaryEmail            | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| dob                       | date             | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| ISRCCode                  | char(3)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| Biography                 | text             | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| CatalogBeginning          | int(3)           | NO   |     | 0                   |                             |
| CatalogPrefix             | varchar(3)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| AddressLine1              | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| AddressLine2              | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| City                      | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| State                     | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| Language                  | varchar(3)       | NO   |     | en                  |                             |
| CountryID                 | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| Juno                      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| TID                       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| Beatport                  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |

| mainGenreId               | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| subGenreId                | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |

| Hearaboutus               | varchar(80)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| HearaboutusFriendName     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| HearaboutusFriendEmail    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| HearaboutusOthers         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| PromoBanner               | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| Option4                   | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| package_plan              | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| royalty_percentage        | float            | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| Threshold                 | float            | YES  |     | 200                 |                             |
| Tagging                   | tinyint(1)       | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| LogoFile                  | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| PhoneNumber               | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| SalesRate                 | decimal(10,4)    | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| CurrencyId                | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| UserId                    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| LastChangedBy             | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| DateAdded                 | date             | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| DateExpired               | date             | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| paypal_time               | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| isViewed                  | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 1                   |                             |
| Active                    | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 1                   |                             |
| agreement                 | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| manual_agreement          | enum('Y','N')    | NO   |     | N                   |                             |
| Signatures                | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| ein                       | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| Neighbor                  | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| nbr_country               | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |

+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Your code is good enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to assign it to assosiative array is already good approach for what you want to do, because its does not matter how many you go through loop if the process or the code logic become complex it will be the same.

Example :
your code using 2000 loop to complete the job that you handling

somehow you managed to recode it and just using 1000 loop to complete the job with validation handling or assign new variable

The two kind or process will take time with no much different because of the complexity is different

Sometimes its better to do more loop rather than focusing in how to make the code do less loop.

I do facing this problem before, then do benchmark between two code, the result is not much different

Hope this help you

Good luck

Comment: yeah you are right i was curious while implementing it that am i doing it the right way or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have no critical problem if you have `1000` records. A loop of `2000` times is not a big matter. But you have a problem if you manage `1 000 000` or more records because the PHP process will grow too big (and will take time, yes).

In my opinion, when you have many data rows to deal with, you have to change your logic from memory to database or file, to avoid managing too much information in memory.

Is there a way you change your query to the database, to get, either

- The list of playlists
- The content of a given playlist ?

Updated :

According to your DB schema, the table `soundcloud_upload` seems (a guess!) to contain both Playlists and Playlist contents, and the difference between the two is known by the attribute `IsPlaylist`.

Is this is true, to get the list of Playlists you will have to introduce a where clause looking like this : `WHERE sc.IsPlaylist = 1`

To get the content of a given playlist, you will have to know its playlist Id and to select with a where clause looking like this : 
`WHERE sc.IsPlaylist = 0 and sc.PlaylistId = '$playListId'`

Comment: i strongly agree, and i wanted to do it by mysql query too,please see my question i edited it and added more detail to describe my DB schema and the reason why i could not do it via query.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer according to my understanding of your DB schema.

Comment: table `soundcloud_upload` is for tracking all the songs that ARE or WILL BE  uploaded to soundcloud and the `TrackId` and `PlaylistId` inside the table `soundcloud_upload` is actually the Ids assigned by soundcloud when the track is uploaded there or the playlist is created on soundcloud .

Yes to get the list of those songs that were selected to be uploaded as a single playlist on soundcloud, i would have to add the check `IsPlaylist=1`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this by  function

```
example



        $soundcloud_uploads=array(
        array('release_id'=>33,'song_id'=>1,'artist_name'=>'omer aslam'),
        array('release_id'=>33,'song_id'=>2,'artist_name'=>'omer aslam'),
        array('release_id'=>34,'song_id'=>1,'artist_name'=>'Robbie')
        );

       $soundcloud=array();
       $release_id_array=array();

       foreach($soundcloud_uploads as $sound) 
       {
         if($sound->release_id=='33')
        {
          $bbb=array();
          $bbb['release_id']=$sound->release_id;
          $bbb['song_id']=$sound->song_id;
          $bbb['artist_name']=$sound->artist_name;
          array_push($release_id_array,$bbb);
        }
       }
    //finally push array to main array 
     array_push($soundcloud,$release_id_array); 
     $release_id_array=array();
        foreach($soundcloud_uploads as $sound) 
       {
         if($sound->release_id=='34')
        {
          $bbb=array();
          $bbb['release_id']=$sound->release_id;
          $bbb['song_id']=$sound->song_id;
          $bbb['artist_name']=$sound->artist_name;
          array_push($release_id_array,$bbb);
        }
       }

        //finally push array to main array 
         array_push($soundcloud,$release_id_array);
```

Comment: what was asked is if the given approach would have any performance effect , didnt asked for how to do it